# Create a DB with SQLAlchemy(Flask)

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I wanted to create a DB with SQLAlchemey but i keep getting stuck on the same Error and i dont know how to solve it or what i am doing wrong.

My Code and my Terminal

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODI'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Item(db.Model):
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
    db.create_all()
```

[my terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FG2v.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error shows that you are working outside of application context.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   with app.app_context():
       db.create_all()

   app.run()
```

This code will access `db` within the application context. See documentation for [app context](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/appcontext/).

**Update:** This applies to the first error that you have encountered. See Detlef's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77530220/22728462) for the second error.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make a unique assignment of the database entry, you need a column that is defined as the primary key. Entries are found and referenced using this key.

```py
class Item(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the  `db.create_all()` with in `app.context()` and before you actually run the flask application. this will make sure all the db tables are created before starting the application server with in `app` context and explicitly mention that `name` is the primary key and primary_keys must be non nullable and unique.

```py
class Item(db.Model):
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), primary_key= True, unique=True, nullable=False)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
    app.run()
```